# In Android studio, when I click on run, the box opens, which shows different installed devices, but shows no virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio

when I click on run button in android studio latest version, the popup box opens which shows the devices. Although I have created two virtual devices, it does not show any. Even if I create the new virtual device, it is not shown here. But I  can see it in the AVD Manager.
Before that, when I run the project, it used to show "waiting for the target device to come online" even when the emulator was already opened. And the same problem persists on running the same project multiple times and multiple emulators were opened.

Comment: have you tried checking the android versions of AVD devices?

Comment: It is noughat version of android

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the minimum sdk level required by your app is greater than the sdk level of the emulators. Check that the minimum sdk level must be less than the sdk level of your emulators.

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: Go to AVD Manager, in the box you will see the name of your emulator and the API version of that emulator. For you app the min sdk version is in your build.gradle file

Comment: Is it the same thing that I answered or something else?

Comment: It was something else bro